Prevent going back from login page after sign out in .NET MAUI app
I have a .NET MAUI app targeting .NET 8 and I use MSAL.NET for managing identity and access_token's.
I have the following in my LoginPage.xaml.cs which works initially to prevent user from going back after hitting the login page:
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() { return true; }
However, after user signs out and I send the user to the LoginPage.xaml, the user is able to go back to the last page where they came from. So, for some reason the OnBackButtonPressed() line I have in the LoginPage.xaml.cs doesn't seem to work after signing out.
I even tried clearing the entire navigation stack as part of my sign out process but the user can still go back.
To be perfectly clear, I'm using the swipe from the left gesture to go back.
Any idea what may be causing this and how to prevent it?

On which platform do you want to implement this feature? Android or iOS?

What does your login and logout process look like? Can you elaborate on that? Do you want to exit the app when you click the back button while you are logged in?

When a user logs in, the first page they hit is always StartupPage.xaml where I check authentication status and if user is not authenticated, I send user to LoginPage.xaml. If the user is authenticated, the StartupPage.xaml is where I make initial API calls, etc. When the user logs out, I log the user out using MSAL.NET and send the user to LoginPage.xaml. As mentioned in the original post, I also implemented simple logic to prevent going back once the user is on login page. I also tried, as part of sign out process, to remove everything from the navigation stack.

the user is able to go back to the last page where they came from    Are you talking about the last page  referring to other pages in your app, or is it just LoginPage?

Can you share the code that opens the login page initially, and how you are sending them there after logout.

When the user logs out I usually do some personal data cleaning from local storage and call Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell(), so I'm sure there's no possibility of back navigation.
